# Hydrostatic pressure is equal everywhere, however, the answer I'm getting is incorrect

Tags: homework-and-exercises, fluid-dynamics

Question:

> A hydraulic car lift has a pump piston with radius 0.015 m and a
>   resultant piston with radius 0.120 m. The combined weight of the car
>   and the plunger is 2500 N. Assume that the height of the piston and
>   plunger are the same.
>
> What amount of force (in N) is required on the pump piston to
>   stabalize the car?

My try at it:

Since the heights of the piston and plunger are the same, so, the pressure on the car lift and resultant piston wil be the same, therefore, Pressure on the car = Pressure on the resultant piston.

=> F/A = F/A

=> 2500 N / 0.015 = x N / 0.120

Calculating this, I got x = 20,000 N, however, it is incorrect, what am I doing wrong?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here the radius of the pump piston according to your question is 0.015 m.
So the area of the pump piston is πr^2=π(〖0.015)〗^2= A(say)
If x N force require then we create pressure on that piston  is P= F/A=x/(π〖(0.015)〗^2 ).
Hence,
             F/A=x/(π〖(0.015)〗^2 )=2500/(π〖(0.12)〗^2 )
                   or, x= 39.06 N.